# Guidance on Powershell Workflow foreach -parallel (){} functions

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, workflow

I just discovered Powershell workflows and I am experimenting but having some difficulties. I do not know if workflows even have the capabilities to do the following but if they do, I would appreciate guidance to make the following function work.

In short, my function `workflow ProcessFrame` is (hopefully) designed to accepted an array of arrays, look at two fields within the second dimension of the array and if the paired values within one of the second dimension array matches the conditional parameters, return certain values from other second dimension arrays to a new array that the function returns. Okay, I realize this description may have given you a headache so let me create and example with the script.

BTW, I know how to do this with a traditional `foreach` loop but if possible, I want to utilize the `foreach -parallel` capabilities of Powershell workflow to learn a new skill.

Note, whenever I am referring to the "second" or "third" field of an array, I am starting at zero. So, the left-most field I would call field "zero." So, an array of (1,2,3) would be referenced as fields zero, one, and two. I just want to avoid any confusion.

Let's assume the array or arrays is populated as follows (as variable $inputArray):

```
$inputArray[0]:(1,1,FRAME,BEGIN,1)
$inputArray[1]:(1,2,media_type,video,2)
$inputArray[2]:(1,2,pkt_pts,1234,3)
$inputArray[3]:(1,2,pict_type,P,4)
$inputArray[4]:(1,1,key_frame,0,5)
```

What I want the following script to do is process all the second dimension arrays within $inputArray and return key data if conditions are met. Specifically, it should first determine if there exists the matched pair of `media_type,video` in the fields `$inputArray[][2],$inputArray[][3]` in a single second dimension array (in this example `$inputArray[1][2],$inputArray[1][3]`). If not, return a single dimension array with three fields populated `$returnArray=@(0,0,0)`. If the matched pair exists - as it does in this example in `$inputArray[1][2],$inputArray[1][3]` - then it should return a single dimension array with data from other arrays.

Specifically, it should find the second dimension arrays that contain `pict_type` and `key_frame` in the second dimension field `$inputArray[][2]`. It should then extract the matched values of the same second dimension array in field `$inputArray[][3]`. It should then populate the $returnArray with the corresponding values of `$returnArray=@($inputArray[0][0],<value of pict_type>$inputArray[3][3],<value of _key_frame>$inputArray[4][3])`. Please do not worry about the first return field of `$inputArray[0][0]` as the value in the first field of the second dimension arrays - `$inputArray[][0]` will all be the same; it is simply being passed through to the `$returnArray`.

Assuming this is possible with workflow and `foreach -parallel`, I am stuck at figuring out how to tell the function to determine if any of the second dimension arrays have matched `media_type,video` in their second and third fields respectively meet the `if-then` condition. Once I figure out how to do that in a `foreach -parallel` loop, I will move on how to act on that information. Specifically, If they don't meet the `if-then` condition, return a `(0,0,0)` array; otherwise, continuing processing the second dimension arrays looking for keywords in the second field and when found, return the value of the third field within that given second dimension array.

So, here is the skeleton structure I have. I have tried a variety of things but can't get anywhere close to desired results. Thanks for your help.

```
workflow ProcessFrame
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        # The input will be an array of arrays where the first dimension is of variable length (20-45) and the second dimension each have 5 fields.
        # Example (with only two first dimensions - that is, 2 arrays of arrays):
        # $frameArray[0]:@(int32,int32,string,string,int32)
        # $frameArray[1]:@(int32,int32,string,string,int32)
        $inputArray
    )

    foreach -parallel ($i in $inputArray)
    { 
        # Determine if any single second dimension array $inputArray[][2],$inputArray[][3] matches "media_type,video".
        # If not exit function with return array of (0,0,0)
        if ($i[2] -eq "media_type" -and $i[3] -ne "video")
        {
            # the following may now work; it is a placeholder until I know the correct commands.
            Write-Output @(0,0,0)
        }
        # Determine if any single second dimension array $inputArray[][2],$inputArray[][3] matches "media_type,video".
        # If yes, extract key data from specific second dimension arrays and return values
        else
        {
            if ($i[2] -eq "pict_type")
            {
                $pictType=$inputArray[<corresponding array>][3]
            }
            if ($i[2] -eq "key_frame")
            {
                $keyFrame=$inputArray[<corresponding array>][3]
            }

            # the following may now work; it is a placeholder until I know the correct commands.
            Write-Output "$($inputArray[0][0]),$pictType,$keyFrame)"          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am presently trying a workaround where I define an int32 before the loop ($mediaTypeVideoCount=0) and within loop increment variable if the if-then conditions are met. Then, after the loop I can add additional if-then tests to determine if variable equals 1 thereby knowing one of the 2nd dimension arrays meets the condition. Then, if met, I can launch a second loop to search for keywords and return which first dimension array they are in (thought I do not how to find index value of given array) to extract desired values. Nonetheless, I am still hoping for a better approach from SU users.

Comment: In thinking more about getting values from a second loop if the first if-then condition is met, I think I can do something similar to the first loop where I create an empty string variables for each keyword I am looking to capture the paired value. Within the 2nd loop, set if-then statements to identify each keyword in field 2 and once identified, add field 3 to the empty string variable. Then, I can return all the data points I desire. This should work in my case because I know a keyword can only appear once within the $inputArray. Again, if an SU user has a better approach, let me know.